# CouchDB "couchapps" in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, couchdb, couchapp

I'm not a javascript guy.  I'd like to (if possible) write CouchDB applications which live inside CouchDB using Erlang, not javascript.

Before I go any further, there are at least 2 usages of the term "couchapp."  One usage is an application living inside CouchDB, callable by the HTTP interface.  The other usage is some build tool for couchapps called "Couchapp."  I am strictly referring to the first usage of the term, not the second.

I understand that there is some native view server allowing some things to be done in Erlang, such as map reduce functions and what not.  That's fine, and I intend to use it, but it's not what I'm talking about here.  I'd like the ability to have some generic app, written in Erlang, living in CouchDB, and callable by the HTTP interface.

Anyone know if this is possible?  If so, how?

EDIT:  Looks like plugins are the way to go.  But if anyone has any other suggestions, feel free to post.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I only can give a bit of hand-waving:

I can see that in my couchdb 1.6 program folder, under CouchDB\share\doc\couchdb there is a gzipped pdf file that's the release notes with 2 API info sections. That might get you somewhere. But I really think the product was intended to be Javascript oriented.

Another place to look is at apache:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HelpForDevelopers

And an active erlang hacker seems to be this fellow benoit:
https://github.com/benoitc/erica

He wrote the upgrade to couchapp, named erica, in erlang. Maybe some clues there...